# PHP if statement with empty query

Tags: php, if-statement

I am new to coding. I am trying to get a different text on one of my button if the field is empty. The original code is:

```
<?php if ( $clpr_options->coupon_code_hide ) {
        $button_text = fl_get_option( 'fl_lbl_show_coupon' );
        $button_text = '<i class="icon-lock"></i>' . $button_text;
        $class .= ' coupon-hidden';
}
     ?>
```

now I changed it to:

```
<?php if ( $clpr_options->coupon_code_hide ) {
        $button_text = fl_get_option( 'fl_lbl_show_coupon' );
        $button_text = '<i class="icon-lock"></i>' . $button_text;
        $class .= ' coupon-hidden';
    } else {
        $coupon = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clpr_coupon_code', true );
        $coupon == '';
        $button_text = 'Angebot anzeigen';
}
     ?>
```

however it does not change the content it still shows the first if need some help.

Its not about `$button_text` being empty, I would like to change the `$button_text` if there is no content within `clpr_coupon_code`

Thanks for helping...

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Are you sure that coupon_code_hide is being set correctly?  You might step through with a debugger or  write to the screen to be sure the else is hit.  Also, $coupon == ''; just returns true or false and isn't doing anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use `<?php $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clpr_coupon_code', true );
    if ($meta == '') {
        echo 'ohne Code gültig';
    } else {
        echo wptexturize( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clpr_coupon_code', true ) );
      } ?>`within my Wordpress theme I am getting what I want, however I do need to get it within the loop as well :-(